# Relation between series expansion coefficients and original function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, taylor-expansion, multinomial-theorem

So I have a function of the form:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x p_{2m}(x)}$$

where $p_{2m}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2m$. I can expand the function around $x=0$ as:
$$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n x^n$$ for some coefficients $c_n$. I would like to prove that the $c_n>0$. One attempt I made was to write:
$$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n (p_{2m}(x))^n$$
since I know that $p_{2m}(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m\geq1$:
$$p_{2m}(x) =\sum_{j=1}^{2m+1} \,(-1)^{j-1}\, a_j\, x^{j-1}$$
with $a_j>0$. So I thought that I could evaluate the function at $x=1$ and compare the two expansions. Obvioulsy this doesn't work because to evaluate the series term to term one would first need to reorganize the expansion to have the same power of $x$. So, I first have to evaluate:

$$(p_{2m}(x))^n = \sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_{2m+1}\\k_1+\ldots+k_{2m+1}=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!\ldots k_{2m+1}!}a(1)^{k_1}\ldots a({2m+1})^{k_{2m+1}}\,\,(-x)^{\sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} i \,k_i-n}$$
which means:
$$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_{2m+1}\\k_1+\ldots+k_{2m+1}=n}\frac{n!}{k_1!\ldots k_{2m+1}!}a(1)^{k_1}\ldots a({2m+1})^{k_{2m+1}}\,\,(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} i \,k_i-n}x^{\sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} i \,k_i}$$
unfortunately I am stuck. How do I compare the two expansions? Moreover, knowing that $p(x)>0$ is it sufficent to prove that $c_n>0$?

Edit:

There is another important property that I found that I forgot to mention, namely:
$$\frac{a(j)}{a(j+1)}>j+1$$
so:
$$a(1)>a(2)>a(3)>\ldots>a(2m+1)$$
The example in the comments clearly does not respect this property.
With $0<a(j)<1$

Edit 2:

Actually I can give the coefficients:

$$a(j) ={2m+1\choose j}\frac{(2m+2-j)!}{(2m+2)!}$$

Comment: All the $c_n$ or just a specific one ?

Comment: Are all the $a_j$'s positive ?

Comment: I have extracted the sign dependence. Possibly all $c_n$'s

Comment: Here, I edited the question

Comment: $p_{2m+1}(x) =\sum_{j=0}^{2m+1} \,(-1)^{j-1}\, a_j\, x^{j-1}$ does not seem to be correct. Is it $x^j$ instead ?

Comment: you are right,  the polynomial is of degree $2m$. Sorry for the typo

Comment: did you try the simplest non trivial example like $p(x)=(x-1)^2+\epsilon$ say where Wolfram alpha clearly gives bunch of negative $c_n$ starting at $c_2$; see here for $\epsilon=1/100$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+1%2F%281-x%28%281-x%29%5E2%2B1%2F100%29%29+

Comment: I edited the question, I actually have proven a property on the coefficients $a$ such that the example you found is not valid

Comment: let me make sure I understand the problem: you have a polynomial given as $p(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{2m+1} (-1)^{j-1}x^{j-1}$ with $a_k>0, a_k/a_{(k+1}>k+1, k=1,..2m$, while $p(x)>0, x \in \mathbb R$; then you want to prove that $\frac{1}{1-x p(x)}$ has positive Taylor coefficients at $0$ - is this right?

Comment: yeah sounds about right! (the polynomial you write is missink the $a_j$ I assume is a typo)

Comment: excellent - sounds interesting so will think about this; note that $p(-x)=\sum_{j=1}^{2m+1} a_jx^{j-1}$ so you can assume the coefficients positive and (the Taylor series becomes the similar one with $+$ for example) then we know that $p$ has all roots outside the unit disc by Enestrom Kakeya - not sure if that helps as the $a_j$ here satisfy a stronger bound than needed for the result above, but who knows...

Comment: I still think something is off since if we take $p(x)=1/4-x/10+x^2/40$, we have $1/4>2/10, 1/10>3/40$ and $p(x)>0$ but $f(x)$ has the $x^2$ coefficient negative https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Expand+1%2F%281-x%281%2F4-x%2F10%2Bx%5E2%2F40%29%29

Comment: I actually found a way to express the real cofficients of the polynomial

Comment: that's again a completely different problem which now is about orthogonal polynomials and the like (polynomials with combinatorial coefficients) so may require quite a different approach than a general problem with arbitrary coefficients satisfying dome conditions

Answer (score 1):

One way you might tackle something like this is to look at the partial fraction decomposition of $f(x)$.  This depends on the roots of the denominator $1 - x p_{2m}(x)$.  If those roots are distinct,
$$ f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{2m+1} \frac{\alpha_j}{x-r_j} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{2m+1} \frac{-\alpha_j}{r_j^{n+1}} x^n$$
where $r_j$ are the roots.  For large $n$ the coefficient is dominated by the terms for roots of the smallest absolute value. If those are positive, there are only finitely many other terms to check.  Note that if $p_{2m}(x) > 0$ for all $x$, all real roots are positive, which will make the corresponding terms $-\alpha_j/r_j^{n+1}$ have constant sign.  But there may be complex roots, which will complicate matters.

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you could elaborate a bit maybe also in light of the edits I have written. Thank you